# Read in file as arrays then rearrange columns

Tags: python, file-io

I would like to read in a file with multiple columns and write out a new file with columns in a different order than the original file. One of the columns has some extra text that I want eliminated in the new file as well.

For instance, if I read in file: data.txt

```
1   6   omi=11   16   21   26
2   7   omi=12   17   22   27
3   8   omi=13   18   23   28
4   9   omi=14   19   24   29
5  10   omi=15   20   25   30
```

I would like the written file to be: dataNEW.txt

```
26   1   11   16
27   2   12   17
28   3   13   18
29   4   14   19
30   5   15   20
```

With the help of inspectorG4dget, I came up with this:

```
import csv as csv
import sys as sys

infile = open('Rearrange Column Test.txt')
sys.stdout = open('Rearrange Column TestNEW.txt' , 'w')
for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
    newline = [line[i] for i in [5, 0, 2, 3]]
    newline[2] = newline[2].split('=')[1]
    print newline[0], newline[1], newline[2], newline[3]
sys.stdout.close()
```

Is there a more concise way to get an output without any commas than listing each line index from 0 to the total number of lines?

Comment: Yes it can be done. Try something first and let us know when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        newline = [line[i] for i in [-1, 0, 2 3]]
        newline[2] = newline[2].split('=')[1]
        writer.writerow(newline)
```

Comment: I adjusted this because I kept getting syntax errors. And the -1 caused no output in file, but I just changed it to 5. I also didn't know that I needed to import csv in order to use it. So I have:
    infile = open('path/to/input')
    outfile = open('path/to/output', 'w')
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        newline = [line[i] for i in [5, 0, 2 3]]
        newline[2] = newline[2].split('=')[1]
        writer.writerow(newline)
The output has commas in it. Is there a way to get an output without the commas and just tab separation?